# Why do self-propelling objects decelerate when a large impulse is applied to it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, drag

I swim frequently. Whenever I push off a wall and start kicking, I keep decelerating until a point, where my velocity stops decreasing and starts increasing again. I tried this with rockets too (in KSP, of course) and the same thing happened - initial large acceleration impulse, then a period of slowing, then acceleration again. Why is this happening? I'm pretty sure this is due to drag overwhelming thrust.

Comment: One thing you seem to ignore is the wave of water you create pushing off the wall. But, to an external observer at least, you don't slow down and speed back up, you slow down to the speed you can sustain by kicking/swimming. (And my personal observations over decades of workouts do not match yours - although I have gotten slower over time, sadly.)

Comment: I'm wondering if you are waiting too long to start "swimming" with your arms and legs?  You are coasting from your push, and only when you reach the lower speed do you start swimming and start accelerating again.  And as mentioned above, the bow wave effect would be very large.

Comment: The rocket motion sounds a bit like a missile of the type that is blasted out of its launch tube by compressed gas, so that it clears the launcher before the rocket engine ignites (ejector launcher).